# android change position of a listview item

Tags: android, listview, position

I'm trying to send an item of a listview that shows an array of telephone numbers to the bottom position of the list with a click on the phonenumber.

My main.xml has the listview plus some buttoms, and R.layout.numberlayout has the layout of the line, with a CheckBox and 2 TextViews (heregoesthenumber and heregoestheid).

I'm trying at my ListNumberAdapter to define a OnClickListener to the TextView heregoesthenumber so everytime you click the number the number does to the buttom of the list. I try to do it with tvn.setOnClickListener, creating a new number exactly the same as the one it was clicked and deleting the original one, but the Checkbox of the ListView looses its

The Main Activity loads the numbers with:
my_Adapter = new ListNumberAdapter(this, R.layout.numberlayout, numberList);
    numberView.setAdapter(my_Adapter); }

My NumberItem class is the class of the phone numbers, with a boolean, and two strings.

NumberListClass extends ArrayList and it has several methods, not relevants to my problem 
public class NumberListClass extends ArrayList.

This my main adapter:

public class ListNumberAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
private NumberListClass numeros;
private Context context;
public ListNumberAdapter(Context contexto, int textViewResourceId,
        NumberListClass listaNumeros) {
    super(contexto, textViewResourceId, listaNumeros);
    this.numeros=listaNumeros;
    this.context=contexto;
}           
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertview;
    if (v == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         v = vi.inflate(R.layout.numberlayout, null);               
         }      
    final NumberItem numberI = this.numeros.get(position);
    if (numberI != null){
        final CheckBox rb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        TextView tvn=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hereGoesTheNumber);
        TextView tvID=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hereGoesTheId);
        if (rb !=null){rb.setChecked(numberI.getStatus());  }
        if (tvn!=null){ tvn.setText(numberI.getNumber()+numberI.getStatus());}
        if (tvID!=null){tvID.setText(""+numberI.getIfSelected());}                                                                                                              

        rb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                numberI.changeStatus();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                buttonView.refreshDrawableState();
            }           
        } 
        );
        tvn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // WHAT CAN I DO HERE???                    
            }           
        });
    }
    return v;}
```

Please your help !

Comment: get the size of you numeros-1.and  store in temp  what you want and delete .then add temp into numeros in the index of  numeros-1 and then notifyDataSetChanged();
                buttonView.refreshDrawableState();

Comment: thanks habib, but It didnt work:    tvn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 NumberItem buffer = numberI;
 Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(buffer.getStatus()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 int bufferPos=position;
 numeros.remove(bufferPos);
 numeros.add(buffer);
 notifyDataSetChanged();
 v.refreshDrawableState(); and the checkbox of the new number created doesn't keep the state of the deleted/added object. Also the checkbox looses its realtion with the list (I check pos 2 and it modifies pos 1)

Comment: I get the solution. I had to change the order of the sentences according to the order of the xml.